# series is truncated after click on the series in the legend

Tags: highcharts

If I am setting the rangeSelector to All, and clicking on a series in the legend. It seems like some series data gets lost or wont be displayed.
I cant figure out the problem, am I displaying too much data? I guess there wont be a problem with the json data structure (I am using the same structur as in all the demos (on the highcharts website)) - mostly it is a 2dim/3dim array.

I will attatch some screenshots of the given problem:

[image: Normal view]
[image: After hiding series]

Comment: If possible post some code or a jsFiddle with basic data that shows this issue.

Answer (score 1):

seems like a general highstock problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqqsE/1/ just added to the given demo from the highstock demos (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) a legend and if you select "All" and hide one of the 3 series, the other series are truncated.

```
legend: {
    align: "right",
    layout: "vertical",
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: "middle"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/eKQcK/1/

I am pretty sorry, but i cant provide example data, because my datasets are quite big - as I said - I am using the same datastructure like the examples on highcharts.com.

```
[[[series1 timestamp, series1 value],[series1 timestamp, series1  value],[iteminformation]],[[series2 timestamp, series2 value],[iteminformation]],[[series3 timestamp, series3 value], [series3 timestamp, series3 value],[iteminformation]]]
```

as you can see in my jsfiddle code, I am using an array called informationarray, which provides information about the series as an array element.

e.g.

```
[seriesname, series max value, series min value]
```

I just added this element at the end of every series array

Comment: Could you paste piece of data? Morever data should have structure: series:[{
data:[[0,23],[1,25]]
},{
data:[[0,23],[1,25]]
}]

Comment: well, its like: [[[1254693600000,1.69],[1254780000000,1.73],[1254866400000,1.74],[1254952800000,1.86],[1255039200000,1.9],[1255298400000,2.01],[1255384800000,2.03],[1255471200000,2.06],[1255557600000,2.09],[1255644000000,2.13],[1255903200000,2.28],[1255989600000,2.78],[1256076000000,2.53],[1256162400000,2.48],[1256248800000,2.44],[1256511600000,2.31],[1256598000000,2.24],[1256684400000,2.34],[1256770800000,2.26],[1256857200000,2.27],[1257116400000,2.29],[1257202800000,2.26],[1257289200000,2.24]]] (for one series) - because I have to set the timestamp somewhere.

Comment: edit: same like: http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=jQuery171021500859936945527_1381925154375&_=1381925154728

Comment: It is incorrect, it should be the same as in my previous example, but instead of 0, 1 it should be timestamp. So as a result should be: 

[[1254693600000,1.69],[1254780000000,1.73]]

Comment: I dont get it, why its incorrec. I have to create a 3dim array because I dont know how many series I will get returned. In the highstock example, they have 3 ajax calls, because they know, that they are going to create a chart with 3 series. So I had to create a workaround (3dim array) which is like: 1dim = containerarray || 2dim = series || 3dim = values (timestamp and value)

Comment: So you have to parpere data in correct format, durign preprocessing to achieve correct figure.

Comment: well, it seems like that there isnt a problem with the data format, if there would be one, the chart wont be displayed correctly in the first place. So could you explain your guess somehow?

Comment: So please preare live demo of your example, without it we cannot replicete this issue.

Comment: Added an example few days ago. Have a look:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZqqsE/1/ (just hide a series via the legend and you will see)

Comment: Which browser do you use? Because in chrome all works properly, I tried to show/hide series / use rangeselector. Which steps should I do ?

Comment: Im using firefox, the problem still exists in chrome tho. The steps are: click on "All" (rangeSelector) -> click on a random series in the legend -> othere series in the chart are truncated